# How to implement BDD using JBehave?

Tags: bdd, jbehave

How to make acceptance test with JBehave with this story? 
I've read many tutorial, but still find difficulty to implement in JBehave.
Could you give example step by step to create it? Thank you.

```
SCENARIO : Accessing Card Payment Page
GIVEN Customer log in at Dashboard
     AND able to see his/her list of Card
WHEN Customer Click Quick Action in one of card
     AND Choose Payment
THEN Customer will be redirect into Card Payment Page which contain information such as ( Name, Card name, Input amount for payment and Input description"
```

Comment: How much hand-holding do you need on this?  I can quickly show you a sample JBehave story file using the information you've provided, but I can't walk you through the entire process of creating steps, etc.  Do you have the JBehave plug-in installed?  What's your framework?  What programming language, etc.?

Comment: what does it mean hand holding?

Comment: i use java programming language, JBehave already installed in IntelliJ. framework : Springboot. I need the to know how to implement it in java. Thank you for your help

Comment: By hand-holding, I mean walking you step-by-step with detailed assistance.  Something most of us here don't quite have the time for.  I simply mean to say "exactly how much help do you need?"  I was going to present your story in story format, but it appears another user (or you?) has already edited the original post to include your story in proper gherkin syntax, marked as code.  Walking you through all the remaining steps would be rather exhausting.  Please be specific as to what you've tried from here and where you need more help.

Comment: What part are you stuck on?  Have you implemented the Java steps for any of the Given/When/Then steps?  Are you able to execute those Java steps?